# C pattern printing vertical numbers using for loop

Tags: c

I am working on a pattern that prints the following code using for loop

```
1
2 6
3 7 10
4 8 11 13
5 9 12 14 15
```

code is as follows, which results in slightly wrong output.

```
main(){
   int i,j,k,n,num;
   printf("\n Enter no of rows: ");
   scanf("%d",&num);
   for(i=1;i<=num;i++,k=num){
      for(j=1,n=i;j<=i;j++,n+=k){
        printf("%d ",n);
      }
   printf("\n");
   }
}
```

And the code gives me this . 
which is wrong from the output i wanted

```
1
2 6
3 7 11 
4 8 12 16
5 9 13 17 21
```

Comment: Start with a peoper signature for `main`. `main()` is deprecated.

Comment: Language used here is "C" , and we are newbies using main () , well that is not the problem here

Comment: The indentation makes your code very hard to read - not the problem but just an observation. What might help is if you add a single line description of what it is you are trying to achieve rather than expecting readers to guess what your desired output represents.

Comment: Take the desired output. Write down all the differences between each number and the number to the right of it. Observe the pattern.

Comment: Being a newbie is no excuse for using obsolete material. If you were learning how to send internet packets, would you be studying Morse code? Using `main()` is very much a problem, because you will be learning other obsolete techniques too.

Comment: Why is `k=num` in the increment portion of the first for loop instead of the initialization?

Comment: @ArkaDutta: As a beginner, you should learn modern C, not ancient K&R-C. The pre-standard signature is an obsolecence feature and due to be removed in a future version of the standard. Also learn to use spaces in expressions and statements. They are not only for indentation and make your code much more readable. Humands are no compilers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion .

Comment: @n.m. Difference between each number and the number right to it ?? Would be highly appreciated if you could elaborate just a little .

Answer (score 0):

The key to this is how you update `n` in the inner loop. You need it to take into account not just `num` but also `i` as you descend through each iteration. I've fixed `num` at 5 here and placed the assignment to `k` at the start of the outer loop as this will always be constant:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, j, k, n, num;
    num = 5;

    for(i = 1, k = num; i <= num; i++){
        for(j = 1, n = i; j <= i; n += k - j, j++){
            printf("%d ", n);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Gives:

```
1 
2 6 
3 7 10 
4 8 11 13 
5 9 12 14 15
```